# Confused about comparison

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs

What is the correct one between:

> Je  mange la plus pommes

and

> Je mange les plus pommes.

?

Comment: None of the above. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Um...my brother and I ate apples and I ate them more than my bro(most apples were eaten by me) sorry if I’m not good at describing in eng

Comment: Nothing forbids you to express it in your native language too.

Comment: ฉันกินแอปเปิลมากที่สุด ฉันกินมันมากกว่าใคร ช่วยตอบเป็นฝรั่งเศสทีค่ะ ขอบคุณค่า

Comment: Google translate gives *je mange la plupart des pommes* (I eat most of the apples) for the first sentence.

Answer (score 5):

The closest to your sentences (both incorrect) is :
"J'ai mangé le plus de pommes".

let's have a look at your sentences :

> Je mange la plus pommes

"La" is the feminine definite article, it is incorrect in this context as it is actually referring to "plus de pommes" (note the use of "de" to link "plus" and "pommes", it is hard to just juxtapose words in French as is done in English, in this case "de" is used to show that it is the largest quantity "of" apples) and not to "pommes" (though "pomme" is indeed a feminine noun, which has no bearing on the gender of "plus"). 
Other problem : you're using present to describe something that *has happened* so, just like in English, you would use the *passé composé* tense.

> Je mange les plus pommes

As above, indeed "pommes" is plural, hence, "les" would be correct if used to point at "pommes", but you're using it to refer to "plus de pommes". Same remark for the tense.

In both cases : "plus de pommes" is a composite locution that can be considered a noun by itself (just as "largest quantity of apples" would be in English), it is neutral, thus, transcribed by the default definite article "le" in French, which happened to be the masculine form.

Comment: I like your mentioning the implied notion of “[the] largest quantity of [whatever]” present in English & how this eventually leads to the equivalent French nominal locution that takes the default/masculine “le.” Granted, OP does state in a comment that there were only 2 apple-eaters (which, at least in English, might mean that OP was really after the French way to say “more apples than” instead of “the most apples”), but I think the use of definite articles in the question itself (even the wrong ones) indicates that OP was marking (& asking about) superlatives, & you answered that very nicely!

Comment: Well, I must admit that my use of superlative, notwithstanding trying to be similar to OP's sentences, stems from it sounding much more natural to my French ears. That's just what I would say to my own brother (though, more colloquially, it would probably be something like "Hé regarde! C'est moi qui ai mangé le plus de pommes!").

Answer (score 3):

None of the sentences written in your question are correct French.

You clarified the meaning of *ฉันกินแอปเปิลมากที่สุด ฉันกินมันมากกว่าใคร ช่วยตอบเป็นฝรั่งเศสทีค่ะ ขอบคุณค่า* with this translation attempt "My brother and I ate apples and I ate them more than my brother" that @user168676 rewrites in correct English to "My brother and I ate apples and I ate more of them than he did."

Here is what I believe best match the intended meaning:

> Mon frère et moi avons mangé des pommes et j'en ai mangé plus que lui.

Comment: Your rendering of the French (since the french is correct I take things from that end) is erroneous; it is understandable in the light of the void that is in the set of English pronouns in this context; there is a rather simple solution and I haven't raked my mind for more but here is that one :

My brother and I ate apples and I  more than him.@jlliagre

Comment: An ngram tells me that the form "Imore than" exists but not "I more than him", neither does the second form exist if to "him" are substituted "them" and "her"; my form is wrong; but I'm still sure that your sentence is faulty.@jlliagre

Comment: @user168676 "My" sentence is the French one. The English one is an attempt to explain the intended meaning written by the OP. It is just here to illustrate the question, not as an example of right English grammar.

Comment: Nevertheless it is wrong, in any case you wouldn't translate it that way; I have nothing for the time being.@jlliagre

Comment: A few seconds' reflection were needed for that one; here is the try, I hope it's convincing, I mean that the form of it will be familiar to you: "My brother and I ate apples and I ate more of them than he did.

Comment: @user168676 I added your rewritten phrasing to my reply, thanks. I'm not sure you understood I wasn't the author of that English sentence but anyway, better to have a right version of it.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out both of the statements are incorrect. Some possible propositions.

> Je mange plus/moins de pommes que lui.
>
> Je ne mange pas tant/autant de pommes que lui.
>
> Je ne mange plus de pommes.
>
> Je mange trop/beaucoup/tant/un peu de pommes.
>
> C'est moi qui a mangé le plus/moins de pommes.

and so on. (Previous phrases are translated below)

> I eat more / less apples than him.
>
> I do not eat as many apples as him.
>
> I do not eat apples anymore.
>
> I eat too much/a lot/so much/a few of apples.
>
> It's me who ate the most/least apples.

Comment: Oh I see,thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Avec « un peu » on ne peut utiliser que des noms de masse. Pensez-vous que vous pourriez dire « Il fume un peu de cigarettes.»? Probablement pas; ce que l'on entend couramment c'est « Il fume un peu.». On est familier avec cela.

C'est la même chose pour les pommes; on ne peut pas dire « Je mange un peu de pommes.». Il est nécessaire de changer la formulation. Une possibilité correcte est la suivante:

- Je mange des pommes en petite quantité.
- Je mange des pommes, mais peu. (Des pommes, j'en mange peu.)

Il ne faut pas confondre avec le cas trompeur « Je mange peu des pommes.»; cette phrase -ci est correcte si utilisée dans un contexte qui convient; le contexte est une comparaison entre par exemple plusieurs sortes de fruits et « des » est alors le partitif « des ». Cela signifie « de la quantité de pommes disponibles je ne prends pas beaucoup de pommes.

La traduction de « Je mange des pommes en petite quantité.» n'est pas « I eat a few of apples. »; cette dernière phrase ne se dit pas en anglais.
Une traduction courante est la suivante, beaucoup comme en français:

I eat apples but not a lot.

Another correction is needed; « C'est moi qui a mangé le plus/moins de pommes.» ne se dit pas et va contre la grammaire: il s'agit de la première personne du singulier du verbe « avoir »; cela est « ai »; donc il faut dire:

- C'est moi qui **ai** mangé le plus de pommes.

On dira cependant:

- C'est lui qui **a** mangé le plus de pommes.